# How to run airflow CLI commands with airflow/kubernetes installed from Helm stable/airflow?

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm

Difficulty running airflow commands when running Airflow on Kubernetes that I installed from the Helm stable/airflow repo. For instance I try to exec into the scheduler pod and run `airflow list` and I get the following error:

```
airflow.exceptions.AirflowConfigException: error: cannot use sqlite with the KubernetesExecutor airlow
```

Ok so I switch to the celery executor.

Same thing

```
airflow.exceptions.AirflowConfigException: error: cannot use sqlite with the CeleryExecutor
```

So what is the correct way to run airflow CLI commands when running on K8s?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you are using `bash`. `/home/airflow/.bashrc` imports the environment variables from `/home/airflow/airflow_env.sh` to setup the connection. The following are some examples:

```bash
kubectl exec -ti airflow-scheduler-nnn-nnn -- /bin/bash
$ airflow list_dags
```

Or with shell you can import the env vars yourself:

```bash
kubectl exec -ti airflow-scheduler-nnn-nnn -- sh -c ". /home/airflow/airflow_env.sh && airflow list_dags"
```

Comment: such a simple solution. Thank you.

Comment: If your airflow installation in not on the default namespace, you need to specify it: `kubectl exec -it airflow-scheduler-nnn-nnn --namespace airflow -- /bin/bash` for namespace="airflow", otherwise kubectl will return `pods "airflow-scheduler-nnn-nnn" not found`.